# How to echo mysql SELECT COUNT(*) using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a count of all the "open" work orders in my table by using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM work_orders WHERE `status` = 'open';
```

I'm just having trouble echoing this to the page using the improved mysqli method.

Comment: If you are looking for a column name you can use an alias: `select count(*) as cnt from ...`

Comment: @juergend thanks for taking the time to respond.  How would I echo it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql aliases for this,

SQL aliases are used to give a table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.

Aliases are often used to make column names more readable.

An alias only exists for the duration of that query.

An alias is created with the AS keyword.

```
SELECT name,COUNT(*) as count  FROM work_orders WHERE `status` = 'open';
```

so when you echo it, you just need to echo using `count`
as

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {             
    $posts['post_id'] = $row['count']; 
}
```